# freeCodeCamp: I am stuck at Manage Packages with NPM

Tags: json, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am on freeCodeCamp, have reached [this challenge](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/manage-packages-with-npm). I have completed installing NPM, started a project and installed a module too, but I am stuck at NPM TEST which says:

Now you've installed something, and used `npm ls` to show what's going on. If you look at the `package.json` file, it has this rather odd bit in it:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

npm can be used as a task runner, and almost every module and project
will have a test script that runs to make sure everything is good.  In
order to help remind you to do this, npm puts a "always failing" test
in there by default.

First, create a file called `test.js`. It doesn't have to do anything,
really. (This is npm class, not testing class.) But it has to exit
without throwing an error, or else the test fails.

Then, edit your `package.json` file to make your scripts section look like
this instead:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "node test.js"
},
```

Once that's done, run `how-to-nom verify` to check your work.

I tried couple of things I got online to create `test.js`, but I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: `test.js` is just an empty JS file in the root of your project (same location as `package.json` file). I'm guessing the command `how-to-nom verify` will trigger `npm test` and verify that everything runs properly. If you include the empty `test.js` file at the root, you should be fine.

Comment: That was quick, thanks for that, will you guide me on how to create a simple test.js file? the commands I tried multiple commands and read documentation, but couldn't get it.

Comment: Oh, are you attempting to create the file from your terminal? Try `touch test.js`. Or just open the root directory in your file explorer and `right click > new file > rename to test.js`

Comment: I did that, I am not sure how to share a screen shot, but I did created a new file test.js and kept it empty.  but i didn't got this point which says                         
First, create a file called `test.js`.  It doesn't have to do anything,
really.  (This is npm class, not testing class.)  But it has to exit
without throwing an error, or else the test fails. like, what do I do next? when i run the verify test. it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an empty `test.js` file and edit your `package.json` file. Chances are you missed this step.

In order to pass the test, you need to update the `echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1` line with `node test.js`. As it is an empty file, it won't throw any error and once you run the `how-to-npm verify` command it will pass.